# OpenLayers 3 - popup auto pan

Tags: javascript, openlayers, qgis2web, html-popup

I created a simple OpenLayers3 map with the plugin Qgis2web.
It consists of a basemap with points. Every point has its own popup. This is the html code for the map and for the popup.

```
<div id="map">
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The popup content is often large, and I need the function "autopan" to move the map to show the entire content of the popup. I modified the javascript code created by Qgis2web this way, as I found in some examples on the web:

```
var overlayPopup = new ol.Overlay(/** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
element: container,
positioning: 'center-center',
autoPan: true,
autoPanAnimation: {
duration: 450
},
}));
```

The result is that sometimes the autopan works, and sometimes it doesn't work. There is not a rule, as far as I can see.
How can I modify the code to make it always work?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console (F12 to open dev tools, then click Console tab)?

Comment: @TomChadwin No errors just checked